# Unable to read repository at https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/sts4/update/e4.13/content.xml

Tags: java

I am trying to install spring tool suit in eclipse from eclipse marketplace. 
But getting bellow error while trying to install it.

Unable to read repository at https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/sts4/update/e4.13/content.xml.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

When i am trying to hit above URL, i am getting bellow error

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>356241D0D1B5248C</RequestId>
<HostId>
vfMu89by+K4LmCONsbeSpbc8v2z/s0QdFA6j1EXHV6MhtFiOlH7vCfIxiXNOeBxzzrQRVWDmewE=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: Nothing you can do about it other than wait or find another download source. Try downloading it directly from https://spring.io/tools -- possibly the repository has been moved/deleted, possibly because of a new release, and you may need to refresh your eclipse marketplace metadata to get the new version.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/208